# How to properly use NSPopUpButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nspopupbutton, nsstringencoding

I have a NSPopUpButton that I want to use to select the text encoding for opening a file.

I already have some ideas how to implement this, but as I'm starting to learn Objective-C and Cocoa I'm almost sure that there is a better way to accomplish what i want.

I need to have a NSString with the name of the encoding and an associated NSStringEncoding value.

I have thought creating a class representing an encoding (name and value) and have a NSArray with objects of this type and then populate the NSPopUpButton with the contents of the array, but I think that there should be a better way.

I'm not very familiar with the NSDictionary class but I suspect that should make things easier.

Can someone give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the dictionary with encodings as value and the names for the NSPopUpButton as keys

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
NSNumber numberWithLong:NSASCIIStringEncoding], @"ASCII", 
[NSNumber numberWithLong:NSUnicodeStringEncoding], @"Unicode", nil];
```

Then add them to the NSPopUpButton with

```
[myPopUpButton addItemsWithTitles:[dict allKeys]]
```

Then get the encoding the user selected with

```
[dict objectForKey:[myPopUpButton titleOfSelectedItem]]
```

Note: you will need to wrap the string encoding enum in a object, like NSValue or NSNumber.

Comment: NSStringEncoding values are not objects, so I guess I will have to use `[NSNumber numberWithLong:NSASCIIStringEncoding]` for the object of the dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys methode. Right?

Comment: Oops, yeah you need to wrap them in a NSNumber or NSValue.

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle this much simpler. The `NSPopupButton` has an NSMenu object with all the `NSMenuItem`s you let the user choose from.

The basic API of NSPopupButton only allows adding simple "itemWithTitle" but not otherwise customize and modify the menu-items created.

```
- (void)addItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
```

But as soon as you called this, you can use the following `NSPopupButton` API:

```
@property (nullable, readonly, strong) NSMenuItem *lastItem;
```

to get hold of the internal NSMenuItem object created with your specified title, and them customize it directly.

Here - you can use the fact that NSMenuItem can be assigned a numeric 'tag', and tag the menu item with your actual encoding (which is an integer).

Then, handling the user's choice is straightforward -- the NSPopUpButton **action** called, gives you always the 'sender' (which object sent the action) that will be the actual NSMenuItem selected by the user. You can simply ask it for its tag - and there you have it. The text encoding the user chose.

So... the code will look like this:

```
NSPopUpButton *pop = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] init];
// add a new menu item for ASCII
[pop addItemWithTitle:@"ASCII Encoding";
NSMenuItem *popUpItem = pop.lastItem;
[popUpItem setTag: NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

And then, in your menu action:

- (IBAction)encodingMenuAction:(id)sender {
  NSStringEncoding selectedEncoding = (NSStringEncoding)[sender tag];
  // do whatever you want to do with the encoding
  }

or, at any time you want to know what is the currently selected encoding:

```
   NSStringEncoding selectedEncoding = (NSStringEncoding)[[pop selectedItem ] tag];
```